# Set AT command through TCP using Ip and Port number in c#

Tags: c#, at-command

How to send AT command to any hardware through its ip and port number. HW is connected with internet. Any possible way doing this with c#?

Comment: Did you read the updated answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can send and receive AT commands after reading this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290414/at-commands-send-receive-sms).

Also you can read this tutorial which includes its source code for that :

[C# Programming: Sending SMS using AT Commands](http://circuitfreak.blogspot.com/2013/03/c-programming-sending-sms-using-at.html)

And here is the [Source Code](https://github.com/CircuitFreakCoder/CSharp_SMS/blob/master/CSharp_SMS/Form1.cs)

Update : If you want to send throgh ip address you should read this :

> Meade's Autostar Suite is delivered with a program called "NetScope" which is actually a telescope Server, listening on TCP/IP and sends commands via Serial port to the telescope.

[How to send commands via network to a TCP/IP-SerialPort server?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8b539d82-7880-4e1e-8000-bbbaf66d07aa/how-to-send-commands-via-network-to-a-tcpipserialport-server?forum=wpdevelop)

Hope it helps

Comment: But my device is connected somewhere else. am just want to set AT cmd using its ip and port. My device never connect with com port

Comment: @MohanK Read this : [Sending through ip address](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SA277&actp=LIST). Also you can read the updated answer.