# how to connect cellphone with com port

Tags: c#, winforms, sms, smsmanager, gsmcomm

I need to add sms service in my c# application. I am trying to use gsmcom sms library.  It says to connect cell phone from com port. I have Nokia X2 and it only allows usb cable connection. After Downloading Nokia PC suite It shows connection to com port4 enabled in Device Manager. 
Whereas when I Tested the GSM Demo it only connects from com port 5.
When I further proceeded and tried sending a message it shows an error No data received from phone after waiting 30046ms and then connection from phone breaks.
Can Anyone help??
I am a student and I don't want to use any sms service that has cost associated 
like MightText, Twilio, vianett and neither do I know any of sms gateways of my country Mobile Network providers
can anyone help? I can attach images of Device information and errors I get

[Here is the complete gsm demo I am trying to use](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290414/at-commands-send-receive-sms

Comment: this is working thanks much

Answer (score 1):

The OP confirmed in the comments above that the following question helped to resolve their issue:

[AT commands Send/receive SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290414/at-commands-send-receive-sms)